# Running 2.83.3 ib Mac Mini Mid 2010

Tags: osx

I have a Mac Mini Mid 2010 running High Sierra 10.13.6. Blender comes up fine, but locks up if I try to do anything -- and by lock up, I mean the ENTIRE MACHINE locks up.

Is there a fix for this? Thanks.

Dan

Comment: I think the problem is the mac mini is likely a 32 bit machine. The latest (and final) version of Blender that has a 32 bit release is 2.80. Just guessing though.

Comment: Perhaps your hardware, in particular the GPU, doesn't fulfill the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/)?

Comment: Christopher, I'll give 2.80 a try, see if that helps. Thanks!